# Check Firebase login state

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm playing with Firebase and i'm making simple app with 3 ViewControllers. First - Sign Up, second - Sign In and third - profile. I already made registration and loggining. I don't know how to check user login state. Profile view controller is initial view controller. How to check user login state when app opening and if user is not logged direct him to login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the current user's sign-in state, you can either get it directly with:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser
```

You'd typically use this in synchronous code that needs to know if there currently is a user, and if so who it is.

You'll usually also want respond to changes in the current user (in fact, this is the more common usage). For that you do:

```
Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
  // ...
}
```

The code inside this gets called whenever the authentication state changes. So when the app starts and there was previously a signed in user, it will fire as soon as that user has been validated. That is usually a great point to update your UI, e.g. directing unauthenticated users to the sign-in view of your app.

For more on this see the [Firebase documentation on getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is logged in, now you can access uesr's properties as followings
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();
    Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
} else {
    // User is not logged in, so redirect the user in hrere.
}
```